# Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that $1$ is the only solution of $x^{p-2}=1$ in $U(p)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that $1$ is the only solution of $x^p-2=1$ in $U(p)$.

My attempt:

${U(p)} = \{1,2,\dots,p-2,p-1\}$
and since $p$ is odd

|${U(p)}$|=even

Is my approach correct?
How to proceed?

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts.

Comment: Use LaTeX. By Euler's theorem, we have $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Therefore you are looking for some element with an inverse of $1$.

Comment: Please do not delete a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3798514/10513) and then repost it. If you want to make changes then you should edit the original question.

Comment: The previous question was wrongly written. The main part of the question was mis-typed thats why I had to delete it. @user1729

Comment: @lulu I have written my attempt. i can't proceed after that

Answer (score 2):

We have $U(p)\cong C_{p-1}$, which has even order $p-1$. So every element has an order dividing $p-1$ and $x^m=1$ means that $o(x)$, the order of $x$ divides $m$. For $m=p-2$ we have therefore
$$
o(x)\mid p-1,\; o(x)\mid p-2.
$$
Conclude now the statement.